# How can I add attachments (Files) to doccuments in couchbase using Spring data JPA in java?

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, spring-data-jpa, couchbase

Here's are the links I referred to http://developer.couchbase.com/documentation/mobile/current/develop/guides/couchbase-lite/native-api/attachment/index.html but there is no mention about usage in service or dao classes.
[spring doc for couchbase](http://docs.spring.io/spring-data/couchbase/docs/current/reference/html/)

This is my dao class

```
    @Repository
public interface UserRepository extends CrudRepository<User, String> {

 }
```

Below is my user model

```
    @JsonIgnoreProperties(ignoreUnknown=true)
@Document
public class User implements Serializable {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = -6815079861643922076L;

    @JsonProperty("docType")
    private String docType = "users";
    @Id
    @JsonProperty("id")
    private String id;
    @JsonProperty("firstName")
    private String firstName;
    @JsonProperty("lastName")
    private String lastName;
    @JsonProperty("password")
    private byte[] password;
    public String getDocType() {
        return docType;
    }
    public void setDocType(String docType) {
        this.docType = docType;
    }
    public String getId() {
        return id;
    }
    public void setId(String id) {
        this.id = id;
    }
    public String getFirstName() {
        return firstName;
    }
    public void setFirstName(String firstName) {
        this.firstName = firstName;
    }
    public String getLastName() {
        return lastName;
    }
    public void setLastName(String lastName) {
        this.lastName = lastName;
    }
    public byte[] getPassword() {
        return password;
    }
    public void setPassword(byte[] password) {
        this.password = password;
    }
}
```

this is my service implementation

```
    @Service("userService")
public class UserServiceImpl implements UserService {
    @Autowired(required=true)
    private UserRepository userRepository;
    public User findById(String id) throws Exception {
        User user = userRepository.findOne(id.toLowerCase());
        return user;
    }
public User create(User user MultipartFile file) throws Exception {
    String fileName = null;
     if (!file.isEmpty()) {
            try {
                fileName = file.getOriginalFilename();
                byte[] bytes = file.getBytes();
            }catch (Exception ex) {
            }
    }
//i want to attach this file as attachment to this user in couch db
    User returnUser = userRepository.save(user);
        return returnUser;
}
public User update(User user MultipartFile file) throws Exception {
    String fileName = null;
     if (!file.isEmpty()) {
            try {
                fileName = file.getOriginalFilename();
                byte[] bytes = file.getBytes();
            }catch (Exception ex) {
            }
    }
//i want to attach this file as attachment to this user in couch db
    User returnUser = userRepository.save(user);
        return returnUser;
}
}
```

And here is my dbconfig

```
    @Configuration
@EnableCouchbaseRepositories(basePackages="com.repository")
public class DBConfig extends AbstractCouchbaseConfiguration {
    @Autowired(required=true)
    private PropertyFileReader propertyFileReader;
    @Override
    protected List<String> bootstrapHosts() {
    List<String> couchbaseHostList = Arrays.asList(propertyFileReader.getCouchbaseHostList().split("\\s*,\\s*"));
        return couchbaseHostList;
    }
    @Override
    protected String getBucketName() {
        String bucketName = propertyFileReader.getCouchbaseBucketName();
        return bucketName;
    }

    @Override
    protected String getBucketPassword() {
        String bucketPassword = propertyFileReader.getCouchbaseBucketPassword();
        logger.debug("bootstrapHosts() : bucketPassword={}", bucketPassword);
        return bucketPassword;
    }
    public CustomConversions customConversions() {
        return new CustomConversions(
                Arrays.asList(StringToByteConverter.INSTANCE));
    }
    @ReadingConverter
    public static enum StringToByteConverter implements Converter<String, byte[]> {
        INSTANCE;
        @Override
        public byte[] convert(String source) {
            return Base64.decodeBase64(source);
        }
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately I think you are getting Couchbase Server and Couchbase lite mixed up they are two different products.

The spring framework you are using interacts with Couchbase Server, which does not support attachments. You can however save binary blobs in Couchbase.

Couchbase lite does support attachments.

Comment: Thanks @Paddy it really helped. Is there spring data jpa for couch base lite? and if itz there will spring jpa supports attachments ?